# Android, Connecting to MySQL using PHP: Null Pointer exception

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, web-services

Im a newbie to android, I am learning to connect to a server through android client using Php, MySql and JSON. For testing purpose im running on localhost.
So for here's what I've done.
**Database demo.php**

```
public class Database_demo extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/PhpAndMySql/category.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               r.add(json_data.getString("category"));
           }
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

**category.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY 'category'.'category' ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`category` (
`category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I am getting a NullPointer Exception, when I execute in android.
Is the Php File correct?

Please I need your help with this!
Thanks

Comment: may use debugger in android and get detailed error from LogCat window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking your php should be as follows (instead of quotes on the table.column use backticks).

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY `category` ASC");
$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Im still getting a Null Pointer exception! :(

Comment: I think it is this part of the code thats throwing error!
[CODE] try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               r.add(json_data.getString("category"));
           }
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));
        }
[/CODE]
The 'result' is not retrieved.

Comment: Does the debugger show you which line number in your code?  If you bring up http://10.0.2.2/PhpAndMySql/category.php in your browser does it show the json encoded string of your categories?

Comment: really need a line number to determine why you're getting exception

Comment: @AaronW. when I open the php file in browser i don't see anything. No json data is displayed.

Comment: @Martin - 'result' in the last try block

Comment: Figured it out 
SELECT * FROM category should be made as SELECT *FROM category 
lol